# Finding the exact directory of the file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, file, directory, python-os

Have a Pandas dataframe with the list of file names:

```
Files
3003.txt
3000.txt
```

Also having three directories in which I'd like to make search for these files:

```
dirnames=[
    '/Users/User/Desktop/base/reports1',
    '/Users/User/Desktop/base/reports2',
    '/Users/User/Desktop/base/reports3']
```

Doing like this:

```
for dirname in dirnames:
    for f in os.listdir(dirname):
        with open (os.path.join(dirname,f), "r", encoding="latin-1") as infile:

            if f==df.Files:

                text = infile.read() 
                print(f,dirname)
```

Gives the error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How is it possible to do properly-rewrite the if conditions or make the for loop in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that `df.Files` is a series, so when you do `f==df.Files` you get a series like `True False False False False...` It's ambiguous as to what single truth value of defines that that series, without any additional information. What you really want is `(f == df.Files).any()` or `f in df.Files.tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add Files.items(). And then compare the files to the iterator generated from that. 'Files' points to the panda Series.

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: "if f in df.Files.items()'